# Not able to get Indexed db data by using selenium

Tags: database, selenium, automation, webdriver, indexeddb

We have an offline mobile website where data is stored in indexDB database and once the system is connected to internet, we click on a button to Sync data to our SQL database. We have a listing page where we fetch data from indexDB and displays in the table. Everything is working fine now. Currently we are trying to do automation on the mobile website using Selenium automation tool. We are using InternetExplorerDriver() of Selenium.

Now, the issues which we are facing here is, records that we are creating using automation is not getting displayed in the table if we open the Internet Explore manually (i.e. iexplorer.exe).

Here are the scenarios: -

If I manually open internet explorer and create record, I can see the saved records in listing page.
If I create a record using automation where internet explorer is automatically opened using InternetExplorerDriver(), I can see the saved records in listing page during the automation process.
Records that are created using automation are not getting displayed in the list if we open the browser manually (iexplorer.exe) and vice-versa.

Is internet explorer that we manually open (iexplorer.exe) and one which opens from InternetExplorerDriver() are different instance? If yes then there is possibility that there are 2 different indexDB. Is there anything like server instance of internet explorer (InternetExplorerDriver()) V/S client instance of internet explorer (iexplorer.exe)?

Any help would be appriciated.

Comment: Not sure about that, but a possible workaround is to launch your internet explorer also through selenium and use it manually. This way you will always get same instances

Comment: @TarunLalwani can you explain how can I launch internet explorer (iexplorer.exe) through selenium . as far as my knowledge I can only launch internet explorer that is a instance of InternetExplorerDriver() not iexplorer.exe.